# Is it possible to show search results by regular expression?

Tags: search, query

Is it possible to show always search results on some page by regular expression? My target is to show documents/pages with a creditcard number in the content. In the regular expression I would like to do something with the creditcard number format "16 numbers with/without spaces after 4 numbers".

**For example:**

4556194864280277

4556 1948 6428 0277